# How to get an "index" from two arrays of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

In a Rails 5 app, I have a situation like this:

```
<% report.periods.each do |period| %>
  <ul>
    <% period.assignments.where('assignments.end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', period.start_date, period.end_date).order('start_date ASC').each_with_index do |assignment, index| %>
      <li><%= index + 1 %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

The result of this code is that each array has it's own indexes. For example if you have two periods (one with 3 objects and the other with 4 objects), then you get the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

The result that I need would be one list of indexes instead of two. Using the example above, I want this:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this result?

Update:

Here is the report model:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :periods, dependent: :destroy    
  has_many :assignments, through: :periods

end
```

Here is the period model:

```
class Period < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :report
  has_many :assignments, through: :programs

end
```

Here is the assignment model:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :assignment_type
  belongs_to :value_chain_activity
  belongs_to :project_type
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program

  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cost_shares, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :progress_reports, through: :recommendations

  end
```

Comment: Can you add your models and schema.db file to your question? It'd be much better to take those queries away from the view and to check how you can get all the assignments at once, without having to query them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get assigments with single query. I'm not sure but this code should work.

```
<% assignments= Assignment.joins(:period)
                          .where(periods: { id: report.period_ids })
                          .where('assignments.end_date BETWEEN periods.start_date AND periods.end_date')
                          .order('start_date ASC') %>

<ul>
  <% assignments.each_with_index do |assignment, index| %>
    <li><%= index + 1 %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This gives us the following error: Can't join 'Assignment' to association named 'period'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @don_Bigote You couldn't share the error message, but I'm guessing the error. I updated the answer. Can you try again?

Comment: @don_Bigote can you share Assignment model class?

Comment: just added the assignment

Comment: @don_Bigote You need to add the belongs_to :period relationship to the assignment model.

Comment: the assignment does not belong to the period

Comment: @don_Bigote try to add `has_one :period, through: :program` to assignment model

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: just place the `<ul>` outside the loop. As far as indexing is concerned: get an array of values and eliminate the duplicates:

```
<% index_values = [] %>
<% report.periods.each do |period| %>
    <% period.assignments.where('assignments.end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', period.start_date, period.end_date).order('start_date ASC').each_with_index do |assignment, index| %>
      <%= index_values << (index + 1) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<ul>
<% index_values.uniq.each do |index_value| %>
<li>
 <%= index_value %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

### Warning

- If you have a large number of records the above might not be very performant for you.
- As a rule of thumb it is preferable you don't make active record queries in your views.

Comment: My problem isn't the <ul>. My problem is the index. I would like to get one list of the indexes instead of two. So, 1 through 7 instead of 1 through 3 and then 1 through 4.

Comment: @don_Bigote i have updated. please take special note of the warnings i have provided.